# What does it mean to edit host file?

Tags: javascript, npm, host

Looking at this [repo](https://github.com/deowk/react-large-list-example) and auto says:

> Make sure to edit your host file
>
> 127.0.0.1 * http://localhost:3001

What does that mean?

Comment: c:/windows/system32/hosts is the file. You gotta edit it with a notepad program that is running in administrator mode.

Comment: Did you try Googling it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: Come on. Google *what is a hosts file*. It's fine to need a little help now and then, but please don't be helpless. At least put a little effort into finding an answer yourself before posting here.

Comment: Actually, that instruction is completely wrong.

Comment: The server you execute the source code on is the host so replace the example strings/data with the host data to enable the script to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a Unix system the file is at /etc/hosts - you will need to be root to edit this.

On Windows it is at C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts or something like that.

Basically your hosts file is local a local Domain Naming System (DNS) - it's convenient to be able to find ip addresses that are local to your network that the public DNS can't know about